# Command 'exiftool' not found (MiniExiftool::Error)

Tags: ruby, exiftool

I have required `mini_exiftool, 1.0.1` and instaled through `gem`. But i till facing the issue of `Command 'exiftool' not found (MiniExiftool::Error)`.

Answer (score 2):

You should install the `exiftool` CLI tool as well, [here's a howto](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/install.html).